# Element Name Attribute in WPF Databinding

Tags: wpf

What is the use of element name attribute in WPF databinding.

e.g.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300" Name="win">
    <TextBox x:Name="txtData" width="100" height="26" Text={Binding ElementName=win,Mode=TwoWay,Path=Data}/>
<Window>
```

Regards,
Priyank Thakkar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's for binding to another element in your application - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname.aspx

In your case you are attempting to bind to the `Window` element with the name **win**.